# Visual Studio 2017 15.4 - Ctrl+Click

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Since I started using Visual Studio with 2003, holding down control and clicking a piece of text would highlight that word allowing for easy copying and pasting. This was the case until I updated to 15.4. Now the same action turns the word into a hyperlink and takes me to its definition (the same way F12 would).

Does anyone know how to change this to behave the way it has for the last 14+ years?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an extension doing that? I installed an extension specifically for this purpose, because vanilla doesn't do it in my experience.

Comment: I have installed no extensions myself, all are out of the box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Open *Options -> Text Editor -> General*
2. Uncheck *Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition*

This definitely turns this behavior off, but I don't know how to go back to VS 2003 behavior, because I've been using Ctrl+Click to go to definition for a long time with extensions.

BTW, I use double click to select word and triple click to select line.

Comment: Phew! That was driving me nuts =)

Comment: In VS2019 (or earlier?) there is a **Use modifier key** drop-down that you can set to something besides **Ctrl**, if you want. I changed it to **Ctrl-Alt** and now **Ctrl** works like we expect.